# how to remove the delay in obtaining data from the Arduino via COM?

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I have an Arduino connected to the joystick. Arduino sends the data via COM port to my PC. On PC, the data processed by the program in Python, in which the circle moving with joystick. The fact is that after a few minutes there is a delay between the joystick and circle.

Code for Arduino

```
#define axis_X 0
#define axis_Y 1

int value_X, value_Y = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  value_X = analogRead(axis_X);
  Serial.print(value_X, DEC);
  Serial.print("|");
  value_Y = analogRead(axis_Y);
  Serial.print(value_Y, DEC);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(20);
}
```

Code for PC

```
import Tkinter as tk
import serial
import os
import sys
import time

#connect to COM
ser = serial.Serial('COM11', 9600, dsrdtr = 1,timeout = 0)

def data():
    time.sleep(0.02)
    serialline = ser.readline().split("\n")
    coord = []
    if serialline[0]:
        string = serialline[0]
        coord = string.split("|")
    return coord

#create window

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=700, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="black")
canvas.grid()

def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
tk.Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle

r = 50
x = 100
y = 100
sm = 200

cir = canvas.create_circle(x, y, r, fill="blue", outline="#DDD", width=1)
root.wm_title("Circles and Arcs")

while 1:
    coord = data()
    x = int(coord[0])/5
    y = int(coord[1])/5
    canvas.coords(cir,x+ sm,y+sm,x+sm + 2*r,y+sm + 2*r)
    root.update()
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is definitively not C and Arduino is also not exactly C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Arduino code, only send the coordinates if the coordinates change:

```
int value_X = 0, value_Y = 0;
int old_X = 0, old_Y = 0;

void loop() {
  value_X = analogRead(axis_X);
  value_Y = analogRead(axis_Y);
  if ( value_X != old_X || value_Y != old_Y )
  {
      Serial.print(value_X, DEC);
      Serial.print("|");
      Serial.print(value_Y, DEC);
      Serial.print("\n");
      old_X = value_X;
      old_Y = value_Y;
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

In the python code, remove the delay (`time.sleep(0.02)`). My guess is that the Arduino is sending data faster than the python code is receiving data, so eventually you have a queue of unread messages for the python code to process.

Comment: Thanks! Now the code for Arduino works correctly. In the python code i added some checks to the received data and now everything works well.